# Can't get to google login page with passport and google oauth strategy

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, google-oauth, passport-google-oauth2

I'm trying to use Passport to have users be able to log in to a web app with with their Google account, but I can't seem to get my login route, /auth/google, to even redirect to the Google login page. My other routes work and I'm not getting any errors in my console, but when I go to localhost:5000/auth/google, the page just hangs and eventually gives a "localhost refused to connect" error (I'm assuming after it's timed out).

Any idea what could be going on? I've used basically exactly the same code successfully in another app - I know I haven't set up most of the scaffolding for full login, but I think it should at least be loading the google login page at this point.

**index.js**

```
import express from 'express';
import cors from 'cors';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import passport from 'passport';
const GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth20').Strategy;

// import database from './server/src/models';
import userRoutes from './server/routes/UserRoutes';

const PORT = process.env.PORT | 5000;
const app = express();

passport.use(
  new GoogleStrategy(
    {
      clientID: process.env.googleClientID,
      clientSecret: process.env.googleClientSecret,
      callbackURL: '/auth/google/callback'
    },
    (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) => {
      console.log(accessToken);
    }
  )
);

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello world!');
});

app.get('/auth/google', (req, res) => {
  passport.authenticate('google', {
    scope: ['profile', 'email']
  });
});

app.use('/users', userRoutes);

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`App up on port ${PORT}`);
});

export default app;
```

here's a link to the full repo: 
https://github.com/olliebeannn/chatterpod

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Figured it out - really stupid mistake. This:

```
app.get('/auth/google', (req, res) => {
  passport.authenticate('google', {
    scope: ['profile', 'email']
  });
});
```

should be:

```
app.get('/auth/google', 
  passport.authenticate('google', {
    scope: ['profile', 'email']
  })
);
```

Comment: Wow I did the same thing... Thanks haha

Comment: I did the exact same thing lol, thanks man

Answer (score 1):

You can also use your original get route too just ensure you append the callback to the req, res. Here's my code example which has been tested...

```
app.route('/auth/google')
    .get( async (req, res) => {
        passport.authenticate('google', {scope: ['profile']})(req, res);
    });
```

This will make your code more consistent with other routes. Also, you may notice that I am using the '.route' on my routes. This is purely for chaining purposes...

Example:

```
app.route('/login')
    .get( async (req, res) => {
        res.render('login');
    })
    .post(async (req, res) => {

        const user = new User(req.body);

        if(user.username && user.password) {
            req.login(user, (err) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    passport.authenticate('local', {successRedirect: '/secrets', failureRedirect: '/login'})(req, res);
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Sorry for the very late advice. Just learning this myself. Hope this helps :-)

Answer (score -1):

just copy this code, which does not need a callback function

```
    app.get('/auth/google', 
       passport.authenticate('google', { scope: ['profile', 'email']})
    );
```

Comment: Hi, I downvoted because this is a copy and paste from the accepted answer. Please, while answering, try to add some value. Take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)